# Excel imported dataframe column header name replacement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, str-replace

I imported an excel table with the original column name as such.

| MAS 183 /1095 | OS (NV) |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 |

Column names appeared with an extra \n at the spaces for one of them and ".1" at the back of both.

| MAS 183 /1095.1 | OS\n(NV).1 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 |

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("\n", " ")
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(".1", "")
```

Did a string replacement on the column header with the above command and the outcome was weird for column name with numbers. All text column name seems ok.

| MAS83 095 | OS (NV) |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to make the column names like in the original? Then you could try:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("\\n", " ", regex=False).str.split('.').str[0]
```

Output:

```
   MAS 183 /1095  OS (NV)
0            123      456
```

Comment: Thanks! Smart way to go around the issue. Any idea why .str.replace(".1", "") does not work?

Comment: @JoshZ you have to explicitly say `regex=False`, like: `str.replace('.1','', regex=False)`